# Could reanimated Nagato revive anyone he wanted?

Tags: naruto

This is question leads from the previous question "Why didn't Nagato revive Yahiko"

As Nagato could use the reviving jutsu in exchange for his life (this jutsu will drain all the user's chakra and die eventually), I thought if he's reanimated, then he will have infinite chakra, he can revive anyone (even himself).
Is it possible?

Comment: for me its sacrificing a life for a life. well he already dead

Comment: I might consider life for a life if it's from Chiyo's jutsu, but this Rinne ribirth clearly said "drain all the user's chakra" not the life itself

Comment: @Shizukura Draining a person's chakra will kill him. Obito was dying when he used rinne rebirth but he survived because black zetsu was stuck to him. The rinne rebirth doesn't really exchange lives, it just uses a huge amount of chakra. So the exhaustion from using so much chakra can kill someone.

Comment: The reanimated Nagato didn't have control over his own body, so he couldn't revive anyone he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

i think the reanimated nagato couldn’t have used the rinne rebirth jutsu because if he could have then uchiha madara would have used that jutsu on himself, because he also had the rennengan and had free will (when he recasted the reanimation jutsu on himself) so he wouldn’t have needed obito to use the jutsu to revive him , even though nagato had access to all of the renningan’s power while being reanimated, maybe there’s a condition to be alive in-order to use that jutsu.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Deidera's ultimate jutsu was far more deadly than using Rinne Rebirth (Obito survived it, after all) and Deidera was fine, Nagato definitely would have been able to recover from using Rinne Rebirth. Alas, he was never given free will while affected by the revival jutsu.

Answer (score 0):

When Nagato was reanimated, he was not under the control of his own body. He was being controlled by Kabuto, so he had to fight any 'enemies' even if he didn't want to. So he couldn't just use any jutsu he wanted unless it was for the sake of fighting his enemies. That's why he couldn't reincarnate Yahiko even if he wanted to.

Comment: Uhh... He is talking about a case were nagato is reanimated. He is not specifically telling about the case were kabuto reanimated him. The question is about a scenario where a reanimated nagato should be using rinne rebirth jutsu to revive someone, maybe yahiko. At a reanimated stage, the person has infinite chakra and the person won't die by normal means. That's the point of the question.

Comment: @ABD could the author confirm this point?

Comment: Sujal Motagi do you remember the time when deidara was reanimated? In that episode, when he was captured by kankuro, he was saying that he should've used self destruction, but repeating it again and again would ruin the beauty of art( it's not exactly what he said, but you get the point right? ). So it would mean that he could use that move infinitely, which also may mean that this applies to rinne rebirth as well.